# How to reference a class in another class C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio, reference

How can I reference a class? For example, I have a `Price.cs` to calculate expenses of items but I cannot use any windows forms controls in my `Price.cs` and have to reference my `Main.cs` in order to use the properties and the controls. Sorry if I sound confusing. English is not my primary language.

Main.cs:

```
    private float? PricePlacement()
    {
        if (serviceDesc.Text != "Multiple")
        {
            if (serviceDesc.Text == "Phone Repair")
            {
                textBlock_Price.Text = "$20.00 + Parts";
                return 20.00f;
            }
            if (serviceDesc.Text == "Virus Removal")
            {
                textBlock_Price.Text = "$10.00";
                return 10.00f;
            }
            if (serviceDesc.Text == "Hardware Repair/Installation")
            {
                textBlock_Price.Text = "$10.00";
                return 10.00f;
            }
            if (serviceDesc.Text == "Software Installation")
            {
                textBlock_Price.Text = "$5.00";
                return 5.00f;
            }
            textBlock_Price.Text = "$0.00";
            return 0f;
        }
        else if (serviceDesc.Text == "Multiple")
        {
            //TODO: Implement a function to check if an item on the itemList is checked or not

            textBlock_Price.Text = "$-.--";
            return null;
        }

        return 0f;
    }
```

Price.cs:

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TicketingSystem
{
    class Price
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot clearly understand what you are trying to do but you can create an instance of `class Price` in your Main.cs like
`class Main{
private Price price;
...
}`

Comment: The dependencies in your app should usually start with your entities (like `Price`, which don't depend on anything), continue with what's called "business logic" (i.e. code operating on entities, ignorant of any UI, dependent only on entities), and then get to "presentation" (a console app, windows forms, web, depends on entities and business logic). So, if a `Price` needs to know about a GUI, you are going in the completely wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was the following.

In `Price.cs` I added `using static TicketingSystem.TicketingSystem;` In the designer

I changed `private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox serviceDesc;`

to

```
          public System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox serviceDesc;``
```

So entirely my new code was:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TicketingSystem;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static TicketingSystem.TicketingSystem;

namespace TicketingSystem
{
class Price
{
    TicketingSystem ticketingSystem = new TicketingSystem();
    public ComboBox serviceDesc = new ComboBox();
    public Label textBlock_Price = new Label(); 

    public float? PricePlacement()
    {
        if (ticketingSystem.serviceDesc.Text != "Multiple")
        {
            if (ticketingSystem.serviceDesc.Text == "Phone Repair")
            {
                textBlock_Price.Text = "$20.00 + Parts";
                return 20.00f;
            }
            if (ticketingSystem.serviceDesc.Text == "Virus Removal")
            {
                textBlock_Price.Text = "$10.00";
                return 10.00f;
            }
            if (ticketingSystem.serviceDesc.Text == "Hardware Repair/Installation")
            {
                textBlock_Price.Text = "$10.00";
                return 10.00f;
            }
            if (ticketingSystem.serviceDesc.Text == "Software Installation")
            {
                textBlock_Price.Text = "$5.00";
                return 5.00f;
            }
            textBlock_Price.Text = "$0.00";
            return 0f;
        }
        else if (serviceDesc.Text == "Multiple")
        {
            //TODO: Implement a function to check if an item on the itemList is checked or not

            textBlock_Price.Text = "$-.--";
            return null;
        }

        return 0f;
    }
}
```

}

I do apologize if this wasn't clear. I am still a beginner and just wanted to help someone out. If this helps you out cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So instead of returning a `float?` from the `PricePlacement()` method I suggest to return an object that can hold both the price and the label text for your controls. You can achieve this by creating a class such as:

```
public class PriceAndLabel 
{
   public string Label { get; set; }
   public float? Price { get;set; }
}
```

and modifying your function to return the `PriceAndLabel` object as follows without having to reference your main (form):

```
    private PriceAndLabel PricePlacement(string serviceDescriptionText)
    {
        PriceAndLabel priceAndLabel = new PriceAndLabel();
        priceAndLabel.Price = 0f;

        if (serviceDescText == "Phone Repair")
        {
           priceAndLabel.Label = "$20.00 + Parts";
           priceAndLabel.Price = 20.00f;
        }
        else if (serviceDesc.Text == "Virus Removal")
        {
          priceAndLabel.Label = "$10.00";
          priceAndLabel.Price = 10.00f;
        }
        else if (serviceDesc.Text == "Hardware Repair/Installation")
        {
          priceAndLabel.Label = "$10.00";
          priceAndLabel.Price = 10.00f;
        }
        else if (serviceDesc.Text == "Software Installation")
        {
           priceAndLabel.Label = "$5.00";
           priceAndLabel.Price = 5.00f;
        }
        else if (serviceDesc.Text == "Multiple")
        {
            priceAndLabel.Label = "$-.--";
            priceAndLabel.Price = null;
        }
        else
        {
          priceAndLabel.Label = "$0.00";
          priceAndLabel.Price = 0f;
        }

        return priceAndLabel;
    }
```

In the form itself you can call the method in a similar manner and it should return your PriceAndLabel object.:

`PriceAndLabel priceAndLabel = PricePlacement(serviceDesc.Text);`

The `priceAndLabel` variable would have a `Price` property which is a nullable float (meaning it may have no value) and a `Label` property which will have the text you want to display on your label in the windows form.

Answer (score -1):

```
PricePlacement priceplacement = new PricePlacement();
...
priceplacement.example = //write code here
```

Remembering that off the top of my head without Googling. If I'm wrong let me know!

Comment: I basically did what you advised but changed some stuff around so I could use the controls.

Answer (score -1):

How to create classes and objects in Visual C#
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307368/how-to-create-classes-and-objects-in-visual-c

e.g.

```
BaseballTeam sf = new BaseballTeam("San Francisco Giants", "Candlestick Park");
```

Yours:

```
Price p = new Price();
...
```